# Nginx rewrite: replace - with /

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I set up ghost blogging platform.
It doesn't allow to insert «/» signs in article links, but I want them to appear in my links, so I want them to be fixed with nginx rewrites.

The link in a browser looks like this:

```
http://blog.site.com/stuff-life/
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
http://blog.site.com/stuff/life/
```

It goes without saying that it should be applied for a number of links starting from "stuff-*", not for one.

I found this, but it's way too complicated for me:

```
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html
```

My config looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name blog.site.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

So how I do a rewrite in my case? Thanks.

Update.

Now I try to do it this way:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name somesite.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.error.log;
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


location /stuff- {
    rewrite ^/stuff-(.*) http://$server_name/stuff/$1 permanent;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


}
```

And it looks like nginx is passing rewrited links to ghost. And I get 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is:

```
server {
# <...>

rewrite ^/stuff-(.*) /stuff/$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/stuff/(.*) /stuff-$1;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

Comment: Is this problem solved? If so, please mark it as solved by clicking the tick mark so that it turns solid green.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the links are in correct format in your software also. `nginx` cannot rewrite links in the pages themselves, you need to handle those other way.

However, making nginx show `/stuff-life` when accessing `/stuff/life` can be done like this:

```
location ~ /stuff/(?<part>.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /stuff-$part last;
}
```